# What kernel file to use for piCore 9 on qemu?

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu

Trying to load qemu with the good old "kernel-qemu" file results in a sync error.

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda piCore-9.0.3.img -kernel kernel-qemu -m 256 -append "root=/dev/sda2"
```

Where can I get a correct kernel for that? The official website has only sources and I would rather avoid compiling my own kernel.